# SSAO Optimization Issue

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I got SSAO working and it look great.

However its slowing down my app quite a bit so in order to reduce the cost the SSAO pass is done using half screen resolution.

But when I multiply the result using a fullscreen quad on the original scene resolution the result is quite ugly... When Im moving the camera around its like looking through a dirty glass... The AO pixels are "bleeding" over especially around the edges.

What would be the correct method to use in order to avoid theses annoying artifacts.

Comment: Bilateral upsampling seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the AO is computed, it is often blurred with texels of similar depth, so there is no bleeding over the edges ([HBAO](http://www.nvidia.com/object/siggraph-2008-HBAO.html), slide 27).

As for optimization purposes, I would rather use [SAO](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/SAOHPG12/) techniques, with the help of [interleaved post-processing](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/docs/BAVOIL_ParticleShadowsAndCacheEfficientPost.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing your texture as float or unsigned?
I don't know for what purpose you use your depth texture, but it could be a good idea to pack the floating point depth to an unsigned RGBA texture, doing the same for the Ambient Occlusion texture.

In addition to this, you can make a great cache optimization by reading the mipmap section in [this paper](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/SAOHPG12/McGuire12SAO.pdf) (the on pleluron linked).